# Mailing List software/app recommendation

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, mailing-list

I'm looking for a simple, preferably free app for managing mailing lists.  I'd like to be able to create groups (Users, Employees specifically).  It should be able to produce good looking HTML emails.

I'm on an PHP/MySQL server, so anything that's online/easy to configure with that would be great.  However, I'd be willing to consider an option which is hosted elsewhere if it was affordable.

Please only answer if you've used the software before and can truly recommend it.  The two I've been considering thus far are PHPList and Newsberry.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, I think that if you care about your newsletters, you better leave it to the pros.

Using a 3rd party hosted service will get you better deliverability, and lots of tools to make sure everything looks good.

One of my favorite is MailChimp.com, which offers a free service if your list is small. (up to 2,000 subscribers. Send up to 12,000 emails per month)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this site? I know one of my friends were using this.
http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/mailing-list-managers/